# Face Recognition authentication android implementation

Tags: android, authentication, face-recognition

i want to implement face recognition and fingerprint authentication in my android app, the fingerprint is already a success but the face recognition is harder to find. Someone with some experience who can help me?

Comment: There's no API in Android for specifically asking for face authentication. You would have to find a 3rd party library for that (which is off-topic here at StackOverflow). Note that an all-software implementation may be more vulnerable to exploits that try to bypass the authentication and/or steal biometric data.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a good example [here](https://github.com/Lauszus/FaceRecognitionApp)

Comment: It is not authentication but It is very simple to change this app to an authentication app.
This app recognizes the face and as you see this app can show the name of the owner of the face. So you can check if the owner of the face has the authorities to unlock.